# Recommended nodejs library for CI scripts

Tags: salesforcedx, node.js

What do you use for CI especially when automating data?

I've been using [sfdx-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdx-node) which somehow wraps sfdx. It's less efficient, dirty and has some quirks that one need to work around (create temp file for bulk/tree/apex to execute). [Here's a wrapper I use](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/f10f3f22db83c36ec28eef75b1c2f20b).

Recently I've realised JSForce would probably fit better, but I like convenience of sfdx provides in terms of authentication. JSForce itself is used in sfdx so maybe authentication wouldn't be that hard. Does anyone use that or something else?

My main use cases (feels like JSForce is more suited for this):

- Execute apex (inlined in JS as template literal)
- CRUD operations on multiple records

Secondary use cases (feels like sfdx more suited for this):

- Get login url for different user
- Create new user
- Assign permission sets

Comment: What's wrong with `force:apex:execute` and `force:data:bulk:upsert`?

Comment: Scripting with bash is royal PITA. nodejs fits every well with jets + playwright.